# Will changing a site from no-www to using www affect SEO?

Tags: seo, migration, no-www, www

My client wants to switch their site from `https://example.com` to `https:///www.example.com`.  I know how to make the switch to having `www` in front of the domain - but does anyone know if making this switch will affect Google Rankings?

Answer (score 3):

as long as you 301 redirect the 'naked' (i.e. non-www) domain to the www, you should be fine.